# Why is Wall Handstand Pushup So Much Harder than Pullup?

Tags: exercise, muscle, strength-training, calisthenics

Why is Wall Assisted Handstand Pushup soo much harder than a Pullup?

I am talking about Wall assisted, where balance is not required. I find it very difficult to go all way down? Is there a scientific, physiological explanation?

I can do Pullups with weights, but can hardly go all the way down with Handstand Pushups.

They are opposite exercises

Thanks,

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your lats are the largest muscles in your upper body (and pull-ups recruit biceps, lower traps, and rhomboids to some extent), and your deltoids are quite small in comparison. So naturally, more muscle mass moving the same weight is easier.